# how can i make some item always in list?

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewholder

I want to make a history message list when I click `customAutoCompleteTextView`, and
I using `BastAdapter` made the red circle part

[image: Image is here]

but I have no idea how to make **"Clear All"** item what that is always visible
, BTW I don't want to add a new item in history's list.
How can I do??

Comment: If you click `Clear All` ,you want to remove history data and other data .Isn't it?

Comment: If it is a custom `AutoCompleteTextView` and you are showing a custom dropdown list then you can add a footer to the `ListView` that your are showing as the dropdown and add the "Clear All" as a button or `TextView.`

Comment: @ KeLiuyue  that's right

Comment: You need a create Custom view which has TableView (construct accordingly max to show) and below a Button for "Clear All". It is not added to Table List. So that, Clear all will always be visible. Hope it answers..?

Comment: @ Pooja Gaonkar  How ?, I have no idea，Could you give a example?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- File created by SkillsOn -->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!--This could be anything that shows your Message list-->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clearAll"/>

    <!--This is clearAll button and is always visible-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearAll"
        android:text="Clear all"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how to set CustomAutoCompleteTextView layout, I do not mean item_layout